# Replace dynamically created image for new image from input

Tags: javascript, dynamically-generated

I'm supposed to display an image after the user inserts its URL. It works fine on the first click, but instead of replacing the previous image with the new URL when the user input a new one, it just creates a new image below the previous.

That's my function so far:

HTML:

```
<p id="tt">Display an image using the image's URL</p>
<label>URL:
  <textarea rows="1" cols="40" placeholder="Image URL" id="url"></textarea>
</label><br>
<label>Caption:
  <textarea rows="1" cols="40" placeholder="Image caption" id="caption"></textarea>
</label><br>
<button id="btn">Add Image</button>
<br>
<div id="imgDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
var getBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
getBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var figure = document.createElement("figure");
  var image = document.createElement("IMG");
  var figcaption = document.createElement("figcaption");
  //attributing the input value in the first textarea as source for the image to be displayed
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  image.src = url;
  image.height = "200";
  image.id = "newImage";
  figure.appendChild(image);
  //making the image a link to its url
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.appendChild(image);
  figure.appendChild(a);
  //creating a Node and setting the input value from the second textarea as caption
  var caption = document.getElementById("caption").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(caption);
  document.getElementById("imgDiv").appendChild(figure);
  figure.appendChild(figcaption);
  figcaption.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementById("menu").add(option);
  //clear textarea after submitting url and caption
  document.getElementById("url").value = "";
  document.getElementById("caption").value = "";
});
```

EDIT - JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hpnLycer/4/

Can someone give me a hint how to solve this?
I tried understanding by reading "similar" questions, but I didn't find any that would solve my case.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle instead?

Comment: Images are quite hard to follow; they're not searchable, for instance.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can help

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient, I hope it's better now

Comment: why you are using textarea? any reason of using it instead of input type="text"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet will be useful

HTML

```
  <input type ="text" id="imageIp" placeholder="New Image url"> <button id ="changeDisplay" > Change Display </button>
<div class ="demoDiv" id = "demoDiv">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.demoDiv{
  margin-top:10px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-image: url("http://freebigpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/shady-forest.jpg");
```

JS

```
var getButton = document.getElementById("changeDisplay");
getButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
var getNewImage = document.getElementById("imageIp").value;
console.log(getNewImage);
document.getElementById("demoDiv").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+getNewImage+"')";
})
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ta41xmwq/1/)

**EDIT**

In the latest snippet you have not defined these two arrays

```
imageArray 
captionArray
```

You need to define them before you can push content in it.I have initialized that at the beginning but you can put them accordingly.But they must be initialized before you can put content in it.

```
var getBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
var imageArray = []; // Initializing imageArray
var captionArray=[]; // Initializing captionArray
getBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

// rest of code

))
```

NOTE:Also in your snippet there is no HTML element with id `menu`,so when I run this code  it thrown an error.

[WORKING EXAMPLE WITH SUPPLIED CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/hpnLycer/3/)

Comment: I've tried putting something like that at the end of my original function and still stacks images instead of replacing it :(

Comment: Omg, I'm a terrible user!!! I'm sorry, I just forgot to remove that part of my original code, which has more functionalities, but not what I'm having problem with. I updated again, in case you have the patience to check again...

Comment: @ClaudiaMoreno What is the error yoour seeing in browser's console?

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't do what I need. I'm trying to use parentNode.removeChild(), but I'm not quite there yet